# Converting CGRect relative to ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my **iPad** app....

**CATEGORY MATCHING APP..**

I have my main view....

In that View I have two sub Views in my main view...

1. Cell View
2. Scroll View.

The problem is when I am dragging a cell view to a scroll view, **cellView** should convert its rectangle relative to the scrollview..

Could you suggest me the

```
Convert Rect ToFrame

Convert Rect FromFrame
```

Comment: That's GOOD TO KNOW. PLEASE fix YOUR **formatting**.

Answer (score 1):

UIView has convertRect methods for this very purpose.  Have a look at:

```
convertRect:toView:
```

For example:

```
CGRect newFrame = [self convertRect:self.bounds toView:nil];
```

This gets a new frame in the same place as the window.